# how to config p2pool so that it can connect to bitcoind wiht HTTPS?

Tags: bitcoind, p2pool

Now I have installed bitcoin with config `rpcssl=1`, and I have tested the connection with a java application. Everything seemed OK.

Then I installed p2pool, and tried to connect to bitcoind (python2.7 run_p2pool.py), and I was faced with the following errors:

```
Testing bitcoind RPC connection to 'http://127.0.0.X:8332/' with username 'pool'...
2014-07-16 15:29:25.036426 > Error while checking Bitcoin connection:
2014-07-16 15:29:25.036567 > Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-07-16 15:29:25.036770 > Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.
```

Then I modified the bitcoin.conf and erased the `rpcssl=1` item, restarted bitcoind. Then I run the command, connecting to bitcoind successfully.

So I wonder how to config p2pool so that it can connect to bitcoind with HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

For using SSL with Bitcoin follow these instructions: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon

Maybe your RPC Connection String have connection type "HTTP"

```
connection-type = "http"
```

Change `http` to `https`

Comment: where to change http to https in P2Pool? I couldn't find this option in P2Pool's run_p2pool.py arguments.